# How do I import this Python extension coded in C into C++?

Tags: python, c++, c

So I really want to import this module into my C++ project: https://github.com/kpdemetriou/pqcrypto/tree/master/sources/dilithium4/ref. It was designed to be used in Python but since it's written in C and uses APIs for Python, I think it may be possible to import it into C++.

My goal: Import this and use this seamlessly like in this example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <"Imported module we're trying to get">

int main()
{
    // Generates and assigns the public key (in bytes) to a variable using the imported C module;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this?
Any other ways I can get this into my C++ file if this isn't an option?
If my question sucks, please comment why!

Comment: I read the readme  on GitHub . `The C implementations used herein are derived from the PQClean project.`

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid, but how do I integrate that into my C++ project?

Comment: The pdqclean readme, itself, has an entire section on building and incorporating it into a project. If you need more than ls there, you’re (imo) quite firmly in the arena of asking for a tutorial.